# How does this C code works?

Tags: c

This following C code is given in my test-book which tells if a digit is repeated in the number entered

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
int digit;
long n;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%ld", &n);

while (n > 0 ) {
    digit = n%10;
    if (digit_seen[digit])
        break;
    digit_seen[digit] = true;
    n /= 10;
}
if (n>0)
    printf("Repeated digit\n");
else
    printf("No repeated dgit\n");

return 0;
}
```

well the problem is that i can't figure out how does this work. In my knowledge it is just calculating remainder through digit = n%10 and nothing else.]

Can anyone tell my how it is working

Thanks Akash

**EDIT:** Ok I edited this part of the code to following

```
if (n>0)
    printf("Repeated digit: %d\n", digit);
else
    printf("No repeated dgit\n");
```

so now it also prints the digit which is being repeated, but i am getting very weird problem.

If i put a digit longer than 10 numbers either it prints wrong output, or it prints that no digit has been repeated.

I thought it might be problem with the array digit_seen[10] = {false} so i increase its length to 20 but then also i am facing the same problem
 can anyone explain why it is happening

Thanks Akash

Comment: And nothing else? What about `n /= 10;`? Take an example and dry run through it. You'll get it.

Comment: OP: What about the lines of `digit_seen[digit]`? What do they do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the remainder of (n/10).  This is the digit in the "one's" place.

```
digit = n%10;
```

Check if the location in the array corresponding to the digit is true.
If so, break out of the loop; the digit has been seen multiple times.

```
if (digit_seen[digit])
    break;
```

Mark the location in the array corresponding to the digit as true

```
digit_seen[digit] = true;
```

Divide "n" by 10, so that "12345" becomes "1234".
When "n" is only a single digit, this will become "0", which will satisfy the loop condition.

```
n /= 10;
```

After the loop, if `n` does not equal 0, then the loop was exited early and multiples of a single digit were found.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the modulo operation gives you the digit in the unit's place. When you do the division and assign it back to `n` in the line `n /= 10`, you are essentially moving one place to the left, thereby giving you a substring of the original number to check.

Let's do this with an example. Say n = 12321. The results are then as follows:

- Iteration 1: n%10 = 1, n/10 = 1232
- Iteration 2: n%10 = 2, n/10 = 123
- Iteration 3: n%10 = 3, n/10 = 12
- Iteration 4: n%10 = 2, n/10 = 1
- Iteration 5: n%10 = 1, n/10 = 0

So, as long as the while loop runs, the number keeps getting divided by 10, and the modulo gives you the units' place digit to check against previous values.