# Using arrays in c to find repeated digits in an number (C)

Tags: c

I need to make a program that checks to see if an entered value has any repeated digits. The user is asked to enter numbers until the entered value is 0. If there are any repeated digits, it displays "repeated digits" and then asks the user to enter another value. If there are no repeated digits, it displays "no repeated digits" and asks the user to enter another number. So far, this is what i have. It terminates the program when 0 is entered, but it always displays "no repeated digits" even if there are some.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
int digit;
long int n = 0;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%ld", &n);

while(n >= 0){

    if(n==0)
        break;
    while (n > 0){
        digit = n % 10;
        if (digit_seen[digit]){
            digit_seen[digit] = true;
            break;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (n > 0)
        printf("Repeated digit: %d\n", digit);
    else
        printf("No repeated digit\n");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (n >= 0) { if (n == 0) break;` better written as `while (n > 0) {`.

Comment: You never set any element of `digit_seen` to `true`.

Comment: if (!digit_seen[digit]){...

Comment: I don't think that `break` belongs there either.

Comment: seems like there is an exact question had been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439817/how-does-this-c-code-works

Comment: You will need to reinitialize `digit_seen` on each cycle through the loop, or include its definition inside the loop — once you get around to setting anything in `digit_seen`.  Currently, `digit_seen[digit]` is always false, so you never set it to true.

Comment: which deosn't the break belong?

Comment: I think the `break` referred to is the one in `if (digit_seen[digit]){
            digit_seen[digit] = true;
            break;
        }`.  I think, however, that the `break` is needed; it is the assignment that is misplaced.  @FredLarson: why do you think the `break` is wrong (and did I identify the `break` you're referring to)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, that's the one. I may have been mistaken.

Comment: @artm: the problem being solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439817/how-does-this-c-code-works is the same — the problems with the putative solution are different.  At that point, it gets tricky to decide 'exact duplicate'; I'd tend to favour "this is not quite a duplicate even though it tackles the same problem" (and some correct code would satisfy both questions, but the explanation of what is wrong would necessarily be different).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think I see it now. The `break` belongs there, but the `digit_seen[digit]=true;` belongs in an `else` to that `if`.

Comment: @FredLarson: yes, although the keyword `else` wouldn't actually be necessary because the `break` would jump around it anyway.  (No harm would be done by using `else`, but no good either.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1:  A `bool` only has two states: `true` and `false`. If you trying to build a frequency counter of each digit seen, for the presence of a digit **more than once**, then you should use a data type that can count to at least two, like a `char` or `short` or `int`, or your own `enum`.

2: This code:

```
    if (digit_seen[digit]){
        digit_seen[digit] = true;
        break;
    }
```

Is never going to be evaluated as true since you initialized `digit_seen` to be `false` at the start of your main function.  What you *should* be doing is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int digit_seen[10] = {0};
    int entry;
    int i, flag = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &entry);
    while(entry > 0)
    {

        int digit = (entry%10);
        digit_seen[digit]++;
        if(digit_seen[digit]>=2)
        {
            printf("Repeated digit: %d\n", digit);
        }
        entry /= 10;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(digit_seen[i]>1) flag=1;
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        printf("No repeated digits\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This identifies all the repeated digits in a number.  The question formally only asks to identify whether there are any repeated digits.  Also, given the input `1111`, it will print that `1` is repeated 3 times instead of once.  The code using `bool` can be fixed to report whether any digits are repeated.  Your code can easily be fixed (`>=` to `==`?) to report any given digit that repeats only once.

Comment: This code does work for the most part. However the user is supposed to be prompted repeatedly until he enters a value of 0.

Comment: I am trying to give the OP a general idea of how to do it properly, not do his homework for him.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed: that's easy to fix — you've been spoon-fed an answer, but you should be able to adapt where it doesn't meet your exact specifications so that they do.  Adding a loop around some code is a trivial example of that, though it might, at that point, be time to put the code into a function and call the function from within a loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int seen [10] ={0}; // we set every element for a number is just 0
    int N,rem;

    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    while(N>0){
        rem = N%10;
        seen[rem]+=1;
        N = N/10;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){ // checking the number seen counts
        if(seen[i]==0){
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d seen %d times\n",i,seen[i]); // just returned the given numbers informations 

    }
    return 0;
}
```